# how to check redux store is updated and then excute a logic in react js

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-redux

Hi I have header component in react. That header is present from Login screen to all other screens. I want to display a Logged in User Name on header once user successfully logged in. But to display that I am checking its value in store and I am getting error for that. How will I know that store has a values and then display it on page after log in.

```js
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import logo from "../Images/Logo.png";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userDetails: this.props.features,
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    debugger;
    if (
      JSON.stringify(prevProps.features) !== JSON.stringify(this.props.features)
    ) {
      this.setState({
        userDetails: this.props.features,
      });
    }
    console.log("componentDidUpdate in header", this.state.userDetails[0]);//this line gets prints 2 times. 1st time undefined hence error in render function and 2nd time getting a value
  }

  render() {
    let userRole;
    if (this.state.userDetails !== undefined) {
      userRole = this.state.userDetails[0]["ROLE_CODE"];// here I am getting error in initial page load
      console.log(
        "features in headers",
        this.state.userDetails[0]["PMX_ROLE_CODE"]//here I am getting error in initial page load
      );
    }
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="d-flex flex-column">
            <div className="p-2 row">
              <div className="col-sm-9">
                <img src={logo}></img>
              </div>
              {this.props.group ? (
                <div className="col-sm-3">
                  Hello <a href=""> </a>
                  <br />
                   {/* want to disply user role here  */}
                  <br></br>
                  <a href=""> View Profile &nbsp;</a>&nbsp;
                  <a href="">Log out </a>
                </div>
              ) : (
                ""
              )}
            </div>
            <div className="d-flex globalStyle">
              <div className="w-100 justify-content-start p-1"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  debugger;
  return {
    group: state.login.userDetails.groups,
    features: state.userFeatures.features,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header);
```

Comment: since you are using redux, I suppose the login status is in the store ? If yes, you need to connect your hearder component to the store and use mapStateToProps  to get the status from the store. Then conditionnaly rendering the header depending on the status. Prior to this, the Login component shoud update the status in the store using mapDispatchToProps

Comment: @Jerome I have followed the way you said but getting undefined values on initial page rendering, I have updated my question. Any help please.

Comment: are you dispatching the status in login? what does redux dev tools show in console?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the userName or any value to the `Header` once you have that in your `App` like this:

```
// in your App.js render method

<Header userName={'User Name'}/> // this can be in your state/redux after you receive this from the API
```

Then your `Header` will look like this

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "../Images/Logo.png";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const Header = (props) => {

  const {userName} = props;
  return (

    <div
      className="d-flex flex-column"
      style={{ display: "inline-flex !important;" }}
    >
      <div className="p-2 row">
        <div className="col-sm-9">
          <img src={logo}></img>
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-3">
           Hello <a href=""></a> {userName}
          <br />
          <a href="">Log out </a>
        </div>
        <div className="d-flex globalStyle"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: I am not getting  user name back from api and in redux store.  How will I pass it from Login to Header. User Name value is in state object of Login component.

Comment: Instead of storing it in the state of Login component, store it in the redux state, the you can access it in your Header component. If you provide a working codepen etc link, maybe it is easier to understand and help you